# Shiny: how to start application with action button disabled?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I need to start an application with "button2" disabled. It should only be enabled after "button1" is pressed. How can I do this?

I'm trying to use enable/disable from the `shinyjs` package.

I can enable "button2" after pressing "button1", but how do I start the application with "button2" disabled?

```
     observeEvent(input$b1,{
        shinyjs::enable("b2")
        ... 
     })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `disabled` in the `UI` definition :

```
library(shinyjs)
ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
      disabled(actionButton("b2", "Click me")),
      ...
    )
```

Another option is to follow [Hadley's answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/renderui-to-create-an-input-thats-pre-disabled/59382/4):

```
ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
      actionButton("b2", "Click me",disabled=''),
      ...
    )
```

To reactivate the button, `shinyjs::enable` works on both options

Comment: This is correct. Note that the `disabled` attribute (using Hadley's answer) would only work for some inputs. It works on actionButton but it won't work on some other ones.

Comment: @DeanAttali, thanks for your confirmation : I wasn't sure that Hadley's answer would work with `shinyjs`, so that I had to test it!