# How to disable one button in a Shiny actionGroupButtons input

Tags: r, shiny

The toy app in the example below contains an R/Shiny `actionGroupButtons` element. I am looking for guidance please on how to start the `actionGroupButtons` with button ‘btn_edit’ disabled, which can then become enabled on a click of the button ‘btn_enable’.

Button ‘btn_duplicate’ should remain enabled at all times.

@DeanAttali mentions the use of the ‘disabled’ attribute here ([Shiny: how to start application with action button disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188379/shiny-how-to-start-application-with-action-button-disabled)), though I think that it is one of the inputs that it doesn’t work with.

Any ideas please? TIA

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    actionGroupButtons(
      inputIds = c("btn_edit", "btn_duplicate"),
      labels = list("Edit", "Duplicate")
    )
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    actionButton('btn_enable', 'enable edit')
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    verbatimTextOutput('btns')
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    verbatimTextOutput('btn_enable')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent((input$btn_edit|input$btn_duplicate),{
    output$btns <- renderPrint({paste(input$btn_edit, 'and', input$btn_duplicate)})
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn_enable,{

    output$btn_enable <- renderPrint({input$btn_enable})

    if(input$btn_enable > 0) {
      shinyjs::enable("btn_edit")
    } else {
      shinyjs::disable("btn_edit")
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You are missing `useShinyjs()` in your `ui`.

Comment: Thnx. Good catch…edited to include.  For confirmation still, that is not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `ignoreNULL = FALSE` in your `observeEvent` call, otherwise it will run only after `btn_enable` was pressed:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    actionGroupButtons(
      inputIds = c("btn_edit", "btn_duplicate"),
      labels = list("Edit", "Duplicate")
    )
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    actionButton('btn_enable', 'enable edit')
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    verbatimTextOutput('btns')
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    verbatimTextOutput('btn_enable')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent((input$btn_edit|input$btn_duplicate),{
    output$btns <- renderPrint({paste(input$btn_edit, 'and', input$btn_duplicate)})
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_enable, {
    output$btn_enable <- renderPrint({input$btn_enable})
    if(input$btn_enable > 0) {
      shinyjs::enable("btn_edit")
    } else {
      shinyjs::disable("btn_edit")
    }
  }, ignoreInit = FALSE, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Another approach would be to disable the button outside of the observer:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    actionGroupButtons(
      inputIds = c("btn_edit", "btn_duplicate"),
      labels = list("Edit", "Duplicate")
    )
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    actionButton('btn_enable', 'enable edit')
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    verbatimTextOutput('btns')
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    verbatimTextOutput('btn_enable')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyjs::disable("btn_edit")
  
  observeEvent((input$btn_edit|input$btn_duplicate),{
    output$btns <- renderPrint({paste(input$btn_edit, 'and', input$btn_duplicate)})
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_enable, {
    output$btn_enable <- renderPrint({input$btn_enable})
    shinyjs::enable("btn_edit")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```